# How to get value out of DockPanel on DataGrid Wpf - Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, window

I grouped my items (products of order) from database by using DataGrid.Group, I grouped it as orders, so it looks like this: *Order Number: #{Here I placed real ID from database }*, example Order Number: #10, and what I want to do now, is to place button next to that text which is contained in dock panel, and when I click on that button I want to do some action with that orders and because I allready have real order id in header I should "take" it somehow, so I can do in code behind something like : remove order, mark it as proceed or something like that, here is how it looks right now and below is code also:

```
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}"   ElementStyle="{StaticResource LeftAligElementStyle}"          Header="Product Name}" MinWidth="350"    Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource LeftAligElementStyle}"     Header="Quantity"   MinWidth="200" Foreground="White"      FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                    <Expander.Header >
                                        <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="dockPanel" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                            <Button Name="btnOrders" Content="Test" Margin="0,0,200,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Order Number:# {0}}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Code behind:

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {


            InitializeComponent();


            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

            CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
            var ordersList = OrdesrController.localOrders();

            collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;


            collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));

            DataContext = collectionViewSource;




        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: btnOrders is not even recognized on code behind like that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle Click event of your Button.

```
<Button Name="btnOrders" Click="Button_Click" .../>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        CollectionViewGroup group = b.DataContext as CollectionViewGroup;
        /* make clever use of this group */
    }
```

Comment: Looks like that's it mate :)